# Call Rails Method from C++ Program

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, communication

I have a rather strange question on C++ to Ruby on Rails communication. I'm trying to update the views in my Rails server whenever certain events happen in my C++ program, both of which are on the same machine. Is it possible to call a method in a controller on a RoR server from a C++ program? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

- If these updates are high-frequency, consider bypassing rails and directly updating your database from your C++ app.
- If the updates are infrequent, you might consider using a C HTTP library like curl to fire off updates to the rails app through the HTTP stack; you may want to restrict access to those update controller methods.
- If the updates are very infrequent, it may just be a sufficent solution to shell out to running a rake task from your C++ app.

While it is technically possible to call ruby from C++ via something like [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) , it does feel like cumbersome solution, which might be difficult to maintain and debug.

Comment: The updates can be somewhat high-frequency, and the data sent does not need to be saved in a database, it just needs to be shown in the view. Curl seems to be an interesting idea... I've found resources for posting via Curl in C++, but not on getting data via Curl in Ruby/Rails... any idea on that?

Comment: If the data is not stored in the database, it will need to live somewhere.  Perhaps you can store the data in memcached, writing it with C++, and read it from memcached in rails when rendering the view?This really depends on what other services you have available in your environment.

Comment: I actually didn't follow that; what do you mean by showing the view? The view is going to get shown to your C++ program. Is it that the program is saving the HTML result of the request for use later? Or is it that you want people using the Rails site to see the same page the C++ program generated by sending in its request?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the Rails application expose its controller methods through XML-RPC -- there's a [library](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails-xmlrpc) for doing just that. Then just use a C++ XML-RPC library to call into it.

Comment: Jason's comment about restricting access applies equally well here, of course.